# How to start an app from the command line?

Tags: applications

I want to start an app with the package name `de.avm.android.fritzapp`
from a shell prompt because it occasionally quits. I have *decompiled* the `.apk` and got the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I have launched certain screens of app by:
`am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN-n de.avm.android.fritzapp/.gui.SettingsTestActivity`

But this is not the same as clicking the app icon on from the home screen.
Upon normal startup, the app registers with the router for receiving IP-calls, etc.

So how can I *simply* start the app as if it had been clicked on?

Comment: You do the same command, but launch a different activity. Depending on the app, you may have a *MainActivity*, but this is up to the developer. Without access to the source (you are not allowed to post anywhere), I can't tell you the name of the main activity.

Answer (score 1):

**TL:DR;**
`adb shell monkey -p de.avm.android.fritzapp 1`

---

**Long Answer**

> How can I simply start the app as if it had been clicked on?

You can start the *main activity* of the app
`am start -n com.package.name/.MainActivityName`

Since you have decompiled the App and got the *manifest file* so you would have the name of the *main activity*. You can get this information from the App's *AndroidManifest.xml* by searching for the *activity* with `intent-filter`and also contains `android.intent.action.MAIN` under action

Check the *activity* element with skeleton as below

```
<activity android:name="this.is.main.activity.name you.are.looking.for">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can start this particular app by
`am start -n app de.avm.android.fritzapp/.gui.FRITZApp`

---

Alternatively if you do not have the source code (*manifest file*), you can try the more general method where knowing the *package name* is enough with the help of [Monkey tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html) as below:

`adb shell monkey -p package.name 1` *(Simplified)*

The above command works because [Monkey](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html) takes a constraint `-c <main-category>` which if not specified will select activities listed with the category `Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` which in turn becomes

`adb shell monkey -p package.name -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1`